# On click add class current to single targeted menu item from anywhere on the website

Tags: jquery, html

I need to use jQuery to create class current on only one specific menu item but from anywhere in the site i want to add a link to effect it. Currently I have some jQuery quoted below that adds class "current" to any menu item on click and removed it from the previous active link.

So i have a batch of portfolio links under my portfolio page that when clicked fade in an out between the different catagories and sub catagories, and currently you can click on them from anywhere in the site and it goes to portfolio page, but doesnt currently add the current class to porfolio menu item.

Below is the links that when any of them are clicked they must always only effect the header menu item portfolio which would be "data-goto="2" and add class current to header menu li as shown lower down:

```
<div id="togglelinks" class="gallery-toggle">
  <ul>
    <li class="people">
      <a class="toggle pt-trigger" href="#" data-animation="59" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#people"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="beauty">
      <a class="toggle pt-trigger" href="#" data-animation="59" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#beauty-fashion"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="stills">
      <a class="toggle pt-trigger" href="#" data-animation="59" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#stills">
      </a></li>
    <li class="mobile">
      <a class="toggle pt-trigger" href="#" data-animation="59" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#mobile">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="specials">
      <a class="toggle pt-trigger" href="#" data-animation="59" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#specials">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Menu item to be effected by the above links:

```
<a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="52" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#people"><li class="menu"><span>Portfolio</span></li></a>
```

Header Menu structure with all menu items HTML:

```
<div class="dotstyle dotstyle-tooltip pt-trigger-container">
  <ul>
    <a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="58" data-goto="1"><li class="menu current"><span>Home</span></li></a>
    <a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="52" data-goto="2" data-toggle="#people"><li class="menu"><span>Portfolio</span></li></a>
    <a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="51" data-goto="3"><li class="menu"><span>Production</span></li></a>
    <a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="48" data-goto="4" ><li class="menu"><span>About</span></li></a>
    <a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="47" data-goto="5"><li class="menu"><span>Contact</span></li></a>
    <a class="pt-trigger" data-animation="56" data-goto="6"><li class="menu"><span>Impressum</span></li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery for the main menu so far that works when you click on the main menu links only:

```
jQuery("a.pt-trigger li").click(function(){
  jQuery("a.pt-trigger li").removeClass("current");
  jQuery(this).addClass("current");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.pt-trigger").click(function(){
        var goto = $(this).data('goto');
        $("div.dotstyle a.pt-trigger li").removeClass("current");

        $("div.dotstyle a").eq(goto-1).find('li').addClass("current");
    });
 });
```

#### check demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/4KSSL/1/

only `Portfolio` and `Production` menu will be work for this demo, coz only 2 sub-menus for goto=2 and goto=3.

If you have all of your sub-menus for all goto 1,2,3,4 and 5. This will work for all.

Comment: Ye but these are completely different menus in different parts of the site, one being in the header and the other being on every page. That structure will create a lot of work to change as other items are effects aswell by these menu's, but I know it can be done without changing anything above with my HTML. The current script will work in conjunction with any other script as it will check for class current anyhow.

Comment: so, you want to add class 'current' to both of your menus?

Comment: Nope, only to header menu, so like my current script only works with header menu, my other menu must also just add the class to it. Here is the current site: http://zero.rosewaterstudios.com now if you click one of the dots on the right it takes you to that page and adds class current, but if you are not on portfolio and you select one of the bottom portfolio catagories, e.g. beauty or stills etc it takes you to portfolio but doesnt add class current to the menu item portfolio.